# When can index funds buy shares of a new stock in the index?

Tags: discussion

Apology again for [When can index funds buy shares of a new stock in the index?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/41192). How can I make in on topic? What's wrong with it? Just edit my post in any way you see fit!

Are there too many quotations? I felt there was, but I kept them to show all the conflicting comments.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the question is good fit for this site to begin with and in addition it is posed in an unclear manner.

1. The question is not about economics at all. When and if some index fund *can* buy some share depends on both external and internal regulations of that company.  For external regulations you will want to ask question at some law related site, for internal regulations you would have to mail the company directly or enquire at their site. Either way the question would not fit this site's scope. Hence in order to reopen it here you should first change it to be about economics.
2. The whole body of a question does not even contain a question, you just state bunch of opinions from reddit and comment on how you are "befuddled" by them. This:

   a) makes it look like you are looking for opinions on those reddit posts - this is why I think people likely closed the question as opinion-based (although I cannot see into their heads and I did not casted my mod vote here).

   b) posting just excerpts from reddit does not show any research effort since in this case it is just bunch of opinions of random strangers without any supporting evidence/research. Even if the question have been about economics I doubt that posting those comments would be received well.